# Selecting "Unfavorite" Displays Wrong Message

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, bookmarks, trivial

When I select "Unfavorite" from the "Question options" menu, it displays the "Post favorited" banner.  It seems to perform the proper function, though.

[image: Selecting 'Unfavorite' renders 'Post favorited' banner]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in version 1.0.52 currently in beta.